# Podman container created but not accessible for many minutes

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, podman

I'm migrating our Jenkins instance to a `podman`-based setup. Everything looks fine, except that there's always a lag of around 5 minutes after `docker-compose` reports that the container has started. Here's the quite immediate output after executing `docker-compose up -d`:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)          docker-container:default
[+] Running 1/1                  0.1s 
 ✔ Container jenkins  Started
```

At this point, the `docker-compose` command doesn't return. Other commands like `podman ps` or `podman logs` also get stuck at this point. I even cannot interact with other containers (like `postgres`) which are running on the same host. However, everything successfully carries on after the busy 5 minutes are over. Then all is fine and Jenkins performs as usual.

During the lag, I can see using `top` that `podman` is quite busy (~100% CPU of 4 CPUs) and with `iotop` I see a lot of disk read access about a dozen `podman` processes. After about 5 minutes, their read activity suddenly ends and the container is up and accessible:

```
    TID PRIO USER   DISK READ  DISK WRITE  COMMAND
1011099 be/4 root  1073.61 K/s   0.00 B/s  podman --log-level=info system service
1011102 be/4 root  1011.27 K/s   0.00 B/s  podman --log-level=info system service
1011341 be/4 root  1066.69 K/s   0.00 B/s  podman --log-level=info system service
1011342 be/4 root   800.01 K/s   0.00 B/s  podman --log-level=info system service
```

Does anyone know what's going on after a container is created and before it's really fully up? Is `podman` somehow reading through the rather large data partition (~250G). What is it occupied with after the container is apparently successfully created?